# MYSQL LEFT JOIN returns unexpected results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `talk_comments` and `talk_comment_votes`.

I run the following code to select, `commentId`, `numberOfUpvotes`, `whetherUserUpvoted`, `numberOfDownvotes`, `whetherUserDownvoted` usin LEFT JOINs to the same table.

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(v1.id) as upvotes, COUNT(v2.id) as userUpvoted, COUNT(v3.id) as downvotes, COUNT(v4.id) as userDownvoted FROM talk_comments c
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v1 ON v1.comment_id = c.id AND v1.status = 1 
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v2 ON v2.comment_id = c.id AND v2.status = 1 AND v2.user_id = 1 AND v2.is_anonymous = 0
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v3 ON c.id = v3.comment_id AND v3.status = 2
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v4 ON c.id = v4.comment_id AND v4.status = 2 AND v4.user_id = 1 AND v4.is_anonymous = 0
WHERE c.id = 2 GROUP BY c.id
```

I have the following data in my talk_comment_votes table

[image: phpMyAdmin database screenshot]

So, according to the query, it should select values `2,2,0,1,1` respectively. When I break those JOIN statements and do the queries, it returns the expected results. But, with JOINs, it returns something like the follows.

[image: phpMyAdmin table results]

Can I get some help on fixing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not the best for performance but try `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` the LEFT JOIN's seams to multiply the count.. Best performing and safest method would be to do the counting in separted subqueries when working with multiple join's

Comment: @RaymondNijland Wow, that returns the correct result. How is it working? Can you explain a little bit? Please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Well the JOIN's make multiple records that will be counted. try the same query without the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` then you will see what is going on there... Or change in the current query the `COUNT` into `GROUP_CONCAT` then you will see "duplicated" records.. Which `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` filters out..

Comment: I see that. Thank you for the answer. If it is not the best performance, what would be the best one?

Comment: By making subqueries more or less like ... `SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) AS alias INNER JOIN table ON alias.column = table.column` or a subquery in a join like `... table INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2) AS alias ON table.column = alias.column`

Comment: I tried that earlier and did a little benchmark, the query with left joins were faster. So, I decided to use it. I'm now trying to run a benchmark with DISTINCT too.

Comment: yea if you don't have indexes..

Answer (score 0):

I'd use conditional aggregation.  A join to a single reference to `tall_comment_votes`, and then check conditions in expressions.

```
SELECT c.id
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 1                                          ,1,0)) AS upvotes
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 1 AND v.user_id = 1 AND v.is_anonymous = 0 ,1,0)) AS userUpvoted
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 2                                          ,1,0)) AS downvotes
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 2 AND v.user_id = 1 AND v.is_anonymous = 0 ,1,0)) AS userDownvoted
  FROM talk_comments c
  LEFT
  JOIN talk_comment_votes v
    ON v.comment_id = c.id
 WHERE c.id = 2
 GROUP
    BY c.id
```

---

This avoids the problem of the partial cross product, when there are multiple rows returned from v1, v2, v3 and v4.

The MySQL `IF()` expression could replaced with a more ANSI standards compliant `CASE` expression, e.g.

```
    , SUM(CASE WHEN v.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS upvotes
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

setup test case and observe execution plans and performance

populate tables

```
CREATE TABLE talk_comments (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
CREATE TABLE talk_comment_votes (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, comment_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, user_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, is_anonymous TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, STATUS TINYINT UNSIGNED, time_ INT UNSIGNED); 
CREATE INDEX talk_comment_votes_IX1 ON talk_comment_votes (comment_id, STATUS, user_id, is_anonymous) ;
INSERT INTO talk_comments (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO talk_comment_votes (id, comment_id, user_id, is_anonymous, STATUS, time_) VALUES (1,2,2,0,1,0),(2,1,1,0,1,0),(3,2,1,0,2,NULL),(4,7,1,0,2,NULL),(5,1,14,1,1,NULL),(6,2,14,1,1,NULL);
```

query execution plans

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT c.id, COUNT(DISTINCT v1.id) AS upvotes, COUNT(DISTINCT v2.id) AS userUpvoted, COUNT(DISTINCT v3.id) AS downvotes, COUNT(DISTINCT v4.id) AS userDownvoted FROM talk_comments c
  LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v1 ON v1.comment_id = c.id AND v1.status = 1 
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v2 ON v2.comment_id = c.id AND v2.status = 1 AND v2.user_id = 1 AND v2.is_anonymous = 0
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v3 ON c.id = v3.comment_id AND v3.status = 2
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v4 ON c.id = v4.comment_id AND v4.status = 2 AND v4.user_id = 1 AND v4.is_anonymous = 0
WHERE c.id = 2 GROUP BY c.id
;

EXPLAIN
SELECT c.id
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 1                                          ,1,0)) AS upvotes
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 1 AND v.user_id = 1 AND v.is_anonymous = 0 ,1,0)) AS userUpvoted
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 2                                          ,1,0)) AS downvotes
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 2 AND v.user_id = 1 AND v.is_anonymous = 0 ,1,0)) AS userDownvoted
    FROM talk_comments c
    LEFT
    JOIN talk_comment_votes v
      ON v.comment_id = c.id
   WHERE c.id = 2
   GROUP BY c.id
;
```

output from explain

```
--     id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys           key                     key_len  ref                        rows  Extra        
-- ------  -----------  ------  ------  ----------------------  ----------------------  -------  -----------------------  ------  -------------
--      1  SIMPLE       c       const   PRIMARY                 PRIMARY                 4        const                         1  Using index  
--      1  SIMPLE       v1      ref     talk_comment_votes_IX1  talk_comment_votes_IX1  6        const,const                   2  Using index  
--      1  SIMPLE       v2      ref     talk_comment_votes_IX1  talk_comment_votes_IX1  11       const,const,const,const       1  Using index  
--      1  SIMPLE       v3      ref     talk_comment_votes_IX1  talk_comment_votes_IX1  6        const,const                   1  Using index  
--      1  SIMPLE       v4      ref     talk_comment_votes_IX1  talk_comment_votes_IX1  11       const,const,const,const       1  Using index  



--     id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys           key                     key_len  ref       rows  Extra        
-- ------  -----------  ------  ------  ----------------------  ----------------------  -------  ------  ------  -------------
--      1  SIMPLE       c       const   PRIMARY                 PRIMARY                 4        const        1  Using index  
--      1  SIMPLE       v       ref     talk_comment_votes_IX1  talk_comment_votes_IX1  4        const        3  Using index
```

measured performance:

```
100 executions                        round 1      round 2     round 3
------------------------------------  ----------   ----------  ---------
multiple left join, count(distinct    0.123 secs   0.130 secs  0.125 secs
conditional aggregation sum(if        0.113 secs   0.114 secs  0.111 secs
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the conditional aggregation would be slower; we could include criteria in the `ON` clause `AND v.status IN (1,2)`, but I wouldn't expect that to make much of a difference, unless there's a slew of rows with `status` values other than 1 or 2.  Of course with large sets, performance will horrendous if appropriate indexes are not defined.

Comment: A test case shows performance of conditional aggregation is 10% faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a benchmark on queries based on @spencer7593 and @RaymondNijland's 2 answers.

**LEFT JOINS wins!**

## 1. Using LEFT JOINS

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(DISTINCT v1.id) as upvotes, COUNT(DISTINCT v2.id) as userUpvoted, COUNT(DISTINCT v3.id) as downvotes, COUNT(DISTINCT v4.id) as userDownvoted FROM talk_comments c
  LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v1 ON v1.comment_id = c.id AND v1.status = 1 
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v2 ON v2.comment_id = c.id AND v2.status = 1 AND v2.user_id = 1 AND v2.is_anonymous = 0
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v3 ON c.id = v3.comment_id AND v3.status = 2
    LEFT JOIN talk_comment_votes v4 ON c.id = v4.comment_id AND v4.status = 2 AND v4.user_id = 1 AND v4.is_anonymous = 0
WHERE c.id = 2 GROUP BY c.id
```

Time for 1000 queries: **0.55000805854797s**

---

## 2. Using Sub Queries

```
SELECT c.id,c.user_id, c.time,c.body, c.reply_to, 
    (SELECT COUNT(v1.id) FROM talk_comment_votes v1 WHERE v1.comment_id = c.id AND v1.status = 1 LIMIT 1) as upvotes, 
    (SELECT COUNT(v2.id) FROM talk_comment_votes v2 WHERE v2.comment_id = c.id AND v2.status = 1 AND v2.user_id = 1 LIMIT 1) as clientUpvoted,
    (SELECT COUNT(v3.id) FROM talk_comment_votes v3 WHERE v3.comment_id = c.id AND v3.status = 2 LIMIT 1) as downvotes, 
    (SELECT COUNT(v4.id) FROM talk_comment_votes v4 WHERE v4.comment_id = c.id AND v4.status = 2 AND v4.user_id = 1 LIMIT 1) as clientDownvoted
      FROM talk_comments c 
           WHERE c.id = 2 GROUP BY c.id
```

Time for 1000 queries: **0.95499300956726s**

## 3. Using SUM, IF

```
SELECT c.id
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 1                                          ,1,0)) AS upvotes
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 1 AND v.user_id = 1 AND v.is_anonymous = 0 ,1,0)) AS userUpvoted
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 2                                          ,1,0)) AS downvotes
     , SUM(IF(v.status = 2 AND v.user_id = 1 AND v.is_anonymous = 0 ,1,0)) AS userDownvoted
    FROM talk_comments c
    LEFT
    JOIN talk_comment_votes v
      ON v.comment_id = c.id
   WHERE c.id = 2
   GROUP BY c.id
```

Time for 1000 queries: **1.2266919612885s**

Thank you for all the answers.